# Beginner Javascript credit hour calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create something in javascript that will allow me to calculate total number of credit hours. I am very new at this and I don't even know where to begin.

Here is what I need to do:

- Create a web page that will allow to calculate totals number of credit hours taken by a student in the semester.
- A page should include separate input fields to enter a number of one, two, and three credit hour courses, taken by a student.
- Then once a result button is clicked, the total number of hours should be displayed. Use function to calculate total number of hours.

Here is what I have and I have no idea if it is even right so don't get mad:

```
<script>
    function doSmth(){

            var value = document.getElementById("credithour").value;
            var doubled = value * 2;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = doubled;

    }
    </script>

    <body>

        1 credit hour: <input id="credit"><br />
        2 credit hour: <input id="credit2"><br />
        3 credit hour: <input id="credit3">


        <button onclick="doSmth()">calculate</button>
        <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML element with `id="credithour"`?

Comment: The doSmth() shows you what needs to be done. Get the value from the input, store the value. Once done then show the result of the calculation

Comment: hate to say this but the method name `get Element By Id` combined with the word `value` should be reasonably intuitive to see what you are looking for

Comment: This is why I need the help, because I really have no idea how to begin this process... Just learning Javascript

Comment: google that method name ...will most likely help. Best resource to read in results will be Mozilla Developer Network(MDN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close but it looks like there are a few things you aren't quite grasping completely.

1. In your HTML you have 3 input boxes declared which is perfect and
   you give them the id "credit", "credit2" and "credit3". However you
   are then only grabbing one of them in your JavaScript function and
   even then you are using the incorrect name "credithour"!
2. Then in your function you are doubling the value you have retrieved
       from the input box when you are meant to be summing them all together!
3. Finally you are displaying it and your code for that actually looks
       ok. There are some security issues around setting HTML using
       innerHTML but if this is just a page for yourself and you aren't
       allowing users to set strings using it you should be fine. Make a note to look into it though.

Although Stack Overflow isn't a code factory I quite like your question, it is clear and shows the effort you have done so far, so I've went to the extra effort of giving you a worked example you can hopefully use and learn from.

It isn't the most perfect JavaScript in the world but it will give you enough to get started.

I also highly recommend jsFiddle for this sort of thing, it allows you to quickly write, test and share JavaScript code with the rest of the world. Click the link below and you'll be able to edit my code, hit RUN and see how your changes affect it. You can also then SAVE your results into your own copy, just hit SAVE and copy the link!

Here is the jsFiddle that does what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/jcos29eb/2/

And here is the revised code:

HTML:

```
<body>

  1 credit hour:
  <input type="number" id="credit1">
  <br /> 2 credit hour:
  <input type="number" id="credit2">
  <br /> 3 credit hour:
  <input type="number" id="credit3">
  <br /> Total:
  <input id="output">
  <br />

  <button onclick="doCalc()">Calculate</button>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doCalc() 
{
  var value1 = document.getElementById("credit1").value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById("credit2").value*2;
  var value3 = document.getElementById("credit3").value*3;
  var total = Number(value1) + Number(value2) + Number(value3);
  document.getElementById("output").value = total;
}
```

My final recommendation is to spend some time going through the [W3Schools JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) it is really clear, easy to understand and covers lots of JS basics and some more complicated things.

Comment: That is almost what I need but I am wanting the total number of credit hours. for example if I have three 3 credit hour classes then I am taking 9 credit hours total. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Then multiple the 3 credit hours by 3 and the 2 credit hours by 2. Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: I should have told you yesterday I figured it out! Thanks for all your help. I think I am starting to understand it more :)

Comment: Great to hear! If this answer helped please consider marking it as accepted so that others who search for the same thing can see it did. It also gives me the awesome rep points and lets others see I sometimes know what I'm talking about. :D